# Inspect react-hook-form registered fields using React Developer Tools

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-hook-form, react-developer-tools

Using the React Developer Tools Chrome extension, is it possible to inspect react-hook-form registered fields at any given point of time ?
i.e. list of fields which have `{...register(fieldName)}` invoked on them